# Failing API query outputs API password to the user frontend

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, security

I have a website with a user input. After the user inputs something, an API (JSON) is queried based on the input.
Every now and then the API query fails and outputs the query URL.

```
 file_get_contents(http://...id=...password=...&input=...): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /www/htdocs/....php
```

The query URL contains a password which is, of course, secret. How can I prevent the page to output the failed request?

Best
Benjamin

Comment: Sensitive information must not be passed as GET parameter..and check your API what it is echoing on failure case

Comment: @Undefined_variable 
I don't send those information via GET. I use the GET to read the input field and build the query URL in a php file that conains the password.
Do you think this is safe?

THanks, Ben

Comment: All the variables after ? in URL are visible in clear text while using http..

Comment: @Undefined_variable : Either I don't get it or I am explaining incorrectly: The form action I use is GET (I do not store the password there), but I use @file_get_contents(MyURL) in a separate php file for the API query. MyURL contains the password. Is the the password in MyURL within @file_get_contents(MyURL) visible in clear text somehow?

Comment: http://example.com?password=abc&username=xyz both xyz and abc will be visible in plain text on the network which can be hacked and also in server logs

Comment: @Undefined_variable : okay, this is pretty bad news, then. Can you see my password here? Because I cannot verify your information: http://www.organic-deals.com/schnoogle/
On the other hand, this is just a "API query PW" which is not extremely secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have error reporting off for a production server, but as a quick fix you can use the error suppression symbol `@`:

```
$resp = @file_get_contents(...);
```

Obviously you will still need to handle a failed call by checking the return value:

```
if($resp==false)//failed
```